# Calculation of sum of infinite products $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n*\frac{r^n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there any analytical solution to this sum of infinite products??

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot \frac{r^n}{n!}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2\cdot \frac{r^n}{n!}$$

Comment: Using the hints given in the answers, you could successively compute $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^k\cdot \frac{r^n}{n!}$$ and obtain as a result the product of $e^r$ by a polynomial of $r$ (degree $k$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for $1$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot \frac{r^n}{n!} = r \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{r^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = r \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{r^n}{n!}$$

Hint for $2$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2\cdot\frac{r^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n(n-1) + n)\cdot\frac{r^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n-1)\cdot\frac{r^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot\frac{r^n}{n!}$$
And
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n-1)\cdot\frac{r^n}{n!}=r^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n-1)\cdot\frac{r^{n-2}}
{n!} \tag{1}$$

You get $(1)$ by differentiating $2$ times w.r.t. $r$ and then multiplying by $r^2$.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{r^n}{n!}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
e^r=1+r+\frac{r^2}{2!}+\frac{r^3}{3!}+\cdots
\Rightarrow r\frac{d(e^r)}{dr}=\sum_{n=1}^{n= \infty}n\frac{r^n}{n!}
$$

So,

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{n= \infty}n\frac{r^n}{n!} =r \frac{d(e^r)}{dr}=re^r
$$

Similarly,

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{n= \infty}n^2\frac{r^n}{n!} = r\frac{d(re^r)}{dr}=r(r+1)e^r
$$

Comment: I am afraid that I don't agree since, at least for me, the result of the first sum is $r e^r$ and for the second $r(r+1)e^r$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - Corrected. Thanks

Comment: You are very welcome !